# Differential equation 2nd order

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

I want to solve a linear inhomogeneous differential-equation of the (second?) order but I don't know where to start and what to do.
We have the differential equation: $y''-y+x^2=0$ with the initial values: $y(0)=-1$ and $y'(0)=1$.
I appreciate any help.

Comment: **Hint:** http://www.math.psu.edu/tseng/class/Math251/Notes-2nd%20order%20ODE%20pt2.pdf

Comment: We don't have $y'$ in my differential-equation

Comment: So what, use Undetermined Coefficients, Laplace Transforms, Variation of Parameters...

Comment: What is undertermined coefficients?

Comment: The link I provided shows that method, but here is another one for Undetermined Coefficients: http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/UndeterminedCoefficients.aspx. For Variation of Parameters: http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/VariationofParameters.aspx, for Laplace Transforms: http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/IVPWithLaplace.aspx

Comment: What methods do you know to solve second-order equations?

Comment: I don't know any. I can only solve some first-order equations

Comment: Are you familiar with Laplace Transforms?

Comment: no i am not familiar with Laplace

Comment: If you don't know or haven't been taught any methods, where did this equation come from? Why are you tasked with solving it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually method of undetermined coefficient mentioned above is not so hard to understand. It is actually used for finding a particular solution. You can find the homogeneous solution by using the homogeneous equation $y''-y = 0$ which has the characteristic equation $\lambda^2-1 = 0$
So you have a homogeneous solution 
$$y_h = e^x+e^{-x}+C$$ where $C$ is a constant.
Then in order to find a particular solution, you simply make a general guess first. In this case, for example I would guess $y_p = Ax^2+Bx+D$ because we have, 
$$y_p'' = 2A$$ 
$$-y_p = -Ax^2 - Bx - D$$ 
so when you add them up, notice you will get  something with the term $x^2$ and also some constant like $2A-C$. So, now you have the equation, 
$$2A - Ax^2 - Bx - D = -x^2$$ 
so you have $A = 1$, $B = 0$ and $D = 2$. Then there you have the particular solution $$y_p = x^2+2$$
Your general solution $y = y_p + y_h$ so the answer is $$y = e^x+e^{-x}+x^2+2+C$$

The reason why the method is called "undetermined coefficients" is, as you can see, while finding the particular solution, you make a guess (it is called "candidate solution" sometimes) with some coefficients that are not determined yet. Then you determine them by using your differential equation.

I also want to add that method of undetermined coefficients is mostly used when you have a constant coefficient differential equation. Because otherwise, making a guess would be really hard. This is where other methods mentioned above takes the place.

Comment: I don't understand why we have $y_p'' = 2A$

Comment: Because we used the ansatz $y_p=Ax^2+Bx+D$, and differentiating twice with respect to $x$ gives $y_p''=2A $

Comment: It is the second derivative of $y_p$, so the first derivative is $y'_p = 2Ax + B$ and the second derivative is $y''_p = 2A$

Comment: Ok fine but how to make those ansatz in general?

Comment: Are we talking about making ansatz about taking derivative or guessing particular solution?

Comment: guessing particular solution

Comment: Well, actually that's why I added the last part, because if you don't have a differential equation with constant coefficients, you probably may not be able to make a guess so you will need another method. But when you can make a guess, i.e. the differential equation is constant coefficient, you can start by considering the non-homogeneous part (in this case we have $x^2$) and it is really about making a good guess by also considering the differential equation ($y'', y', y, etc.$).

Comment: For example if you had $sinx$ instead of $x^2$, then your guess would be $y_p = Asinx + Bcosx$. If you are aware of the fact that in both $y''$ and $y$, the term with coefficient $A$ ends up with $sinx$, then your guess could be even more particular like $y_p = Asinx$ because the coefficient $B$ of $cosx$ will eventually be $0$. But the best way of learning this is practicing it with different problems I think. Then you will be able to see the candidate solution more easily.